# Как повысить/понизить шанс генерации определенного символа?

Tags: c#

При генерации определенного набора символов (цифры + буквы) большую часть, получаемой на выходе строки, занимают именно буквы. Хотел бы уточнить момент, как повлиять на шанс генерации определенного символа или целой последовательности?

Как генерирует сейчас: "FNL6O", "IU46W", "K7UMDNEV"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344255

Comment: Вы хотите управлять шансом появления каждого символа? Такое возможно. А зачем?

Answer (score 4):

Букв 26 штук, цифр всего 10. Шанс появления буквы в 2,6 раз выше. Один из вариантов - это сделать свой набор. Для примера: берёшь 2 набора букв и 5 наборов цифр и получаешь примерно одинаковую вероятность генерации букв и цифр.

```
string data = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
```

Если идти более сложным путём, то можно искусственно выбирать позиции для цифр и записывать туда именно цифры, но это много геморроя, и не уверен, что такая точность вообще критична для вас.
Ещё как вариант, сделать некий валидатор, который будет отправлять строку на перегенерацию, если цифр слишком мало.